# Custom UIStoryboardSegue back direction

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, uistoryboardsegue

How can I manipulate the back direction of a storyboard segue?
I modified the direction a new controller moves into the screen with a custom segue.
The back button in the navigation bar then triggers a "left to right" animation. 
However, I would like it to be the opposite of the segue though which the controller got there.

Below is my overridden perform method

```
-(void) perform{

UIViewController *sourceViewController = (UIViewController*)[self sourceViewController];
UIViewController *destinationController = (UIViewController*)[self destinationViewController];

CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = .25;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
transition.type = kCATransitionPush; //kCATransitionMoveIn; //, kCATransitionPush, kCATransitionReveal, kCATransitionFade
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft; //kCATransitionFromLeft, kCATransitionFromRight, kCATransitionFromTop, kCATransitionFromBottom



[sourceViewController.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition
                                                            forKey:kCATransition];

[sourceViewController.navigationController pushViewController:destinationController animated:NO];
}
```